# How do i get autofilter field indicator to indicate the correct column?

Tags: vba, excel, autofilter

I have a spreadsheet w/30 or so columns. My goal is to filter the set based on 1 column and my approach was the specify a range being just that column and then filter that range. I do have autofilters on every column and when i specify a field:=1 excel picks the first column...whcih is outside of my range. So it's always trying to filter on column "A"...not column "U" as desired. Am i mis-understanding how to use this field? i though it was an offset w/in a range.

here's a simple example

```
Dim r As Range
Dim sheet As Worksheet

Set sheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("test")
sheet.Range("u1:u9").AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:="Will"
```

as an aside...is there a way to get a column number associated with the column letter? for example U --> 21. if so i could select the entire spreadsheet as the range and do an offset of 21

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are applying filters to one column, you will have to clear the existing filters first.

Your tweaked code would be something like this and it will apply the filter to column U only...

```
Sub test()
Dim r As Range
Dim sheet As Worksheet

Set sheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("test")
sheet.AutoFilterMode = False
sheet.Range("u1:u9").AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:="Will"
End Sub
```

OR

You may also apply the filters to all the columns and specify the field criteria correctly.

Give this a try...

```
Sub test2()
Dim r As Range
Dim sheet As Worksheet
Set sheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("test")
Set r = sheet.Range("U1")
sheet.AutoFilterMode = False
sheet.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.AutoFilter field:=r.Column, Criteria1:="Will"
End Sub
```

Comment: sktneer...thanks so much. Two items i didn't know/think of before

Comment: @Cooper5114 You're welcome! Glad you found it helpful. If that resolves your issue, please take a minute to accept the answer to mark your question as Solved. :)